# Name Field Autoupdating does not keep the updated name

Tags: fields

I have lead named "Autmn" and I change it to "Autumn" (correct the spelling). It saves the lead record fine.

Then Salesforce auto-updates (and revert the name to the incorrect name) at 1:05 and 5:05 central time.

I have check my integration with Acton email marketing and this doesn't seem to effect it.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?
I am new to Salesforce so any suggestion to where to look would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the reversions are happening at regular times - well after the initial change - narrows down the possibilities.

The first thing I'd check is whether it's a Time-based Workflow.

- Fix Autumn's name again - preferably not at 1.04 PM
- Go to the setup menu and search for "Time-based Workflow" and click on the link.
- At this stage you'll see nothing. Click Search.
- If we've cracked it, you'll see a reference to the lead you've just edited and a link to the workflow that's causing the problem.
- Depending on your organisation, the workflow you're wanting might be swamped by hundreds of others. You'll need the drop-down menus at the top of screen. For some reason Salesforce didn't see fit to label them. You only care about the first row: in dropdown 1 choose 'Object', in dropdown 2 pick 'equals' and in dropdown 3 *type* 'Lead'. Then click 'Search'.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. No luck though there appear to be no time-based work flows on this organization.

Comment: What are some keyword you think I could use to search for a solution online?

Comment: You could try the Jobs section of setup: look in Scheduled Jobs or Apex Jobs and see if there's anything in there that's running at 5 past the hour.

Comment: I only see some background jobs but none are at the times in questions. I think I am going to try to identify what APIs are being pushed in and out.

Comment: It's a big leap for someone new to Salesforce but you could try creating a debug log for the YogaYoga Admin user.

Comment: I just turned on Field Track History for the "name" field under Leads not sure where I can go review a report of history for the changes. I am trying to pair these changes with API calls from Acton (our only integration) in the login history.